# Maven build on Jenkins - upstream version range resolves to version being built in a concurrent job

Tags: maven, jenkins

We have a Jenkins build which in it's initial stage tries to determine the latest deployed version of some dependencies via version ranges, which are also built by that same Jenkins instance. Each build is for several artifacts, all with a shared version, so we want to select the latest version which has been completed. We do this by using a special pom which has dependencies on specific poms - these are deployed last by the other builds.

The issue is that if one of the other builds is running, but has not yet deployed the pom, maven's version range resolution winds up selecting the version for the build in progress and then fails as some of the dependencies haven't been built yet.

This isn't a downstream build kicked off by the dependency. In any case, we've tried the "Enable isolated resolution for downstream builds" and "Resolve artifacts from Artifactory" but neither have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the Jenkins maven local repository - it looks like in the current configuration this is shared between the builds. Thus, the in-flight build manages to pick up installed poms that haven't yet been deployed.

We solved this by adding `-Dmaven.local.repo=${WORKSPACE}/.m2/repository` for when we resolve the version ranges - this way the build is isolated from the other concurrent builds for this stage.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is a normal UI "maven project" then there is a *Use private Maven repository* checkbox that uses the workspace specific maven repository cache

> Normally, Jenkins uses the local Maven repository as determined by Maven — the exact process seems to be undocumented, but it's ~/.m2/repository and can be overridden by  in ~/.m2/settings.xml (see the reference for more details.)
> This normally means that all the jobs that are executed on the same node shares a single Maven repository. The upside of this is that you can save the disk space, but the downside of this is that sometimes those builds could interfere with each other. For example, you might end up having builds incorrectly succeed, just because your have all the dependencies in your local repository, despite that fact that none of the repositories in POM might have them.
>
> There are also some reported problems regarding having concurrent
> Maven processes trying to use the same local repository.
>
> When this option is checked, Jenkins will tell Maven to use
> $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository. This means each
> job will get its own isolated Maven repository just for itself. It
> fixes the above problems, at the expense of additional disk space
> consumption.
>
> When using this option, consider setting up a Maven artifact manager
> so that you don't have to hit remote Maven repositories too often.
>
> If you'd prefer to activate this mode in all the Maven jobs executed
> on Jenkins, refer to the technique described here.

If it's a pipeline job they a *mavenLocalRepo* setting see: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/

If it was a freestyle job, your only choice to do what that option does by hand

> By using this option, Jenkins will tell Maven to use a custom path for the build as the local Maven repository by using -Dmaven.repo.local
> If specified as a relative path then this value will be resolved against the workspace root and not the current working directory.
> ie. $WORKSPACE/.repository if .repository value is specified.

Comment: Thank you for the information. We’re using the UI but we don’t have that private repository option.